# how to get current cart products custom attribute in cart page?

Tags: magento2.3.4

> hello, I want to get custom attributes name as **hsn_code** from cart products,

> I have added one product to the cart,

> Now I try to get this cart products custom attribute on the same cart page,

> But when I code the product name appears but not the custom attribute, I don't know why.

> **Visible on Catalog Pages on Storefront is Yes**,

> **Used in Product Listing is Yes**

> please help me with this.

my code.

**Data.php**

```
protected $_checkoutSession;
protected $_cart;


$this->_cart = $cart;
$this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession; 

public function getCart()
    {       
        return $this->_cart;
    }
    
    public function getCheckoutSession()
    {
        return $this->_checkoutSession;
    }
```

**newtax.php**

```
if($Cartinfo = $this->helperData->getCheckoutSession()->getQuote()){
                $items = $Cartinfo->getAllItems();
                foreach($items as $item) {
                    $name = $item->getName();
                    $hsncode = $item->getData('hsn_code');
                    //$hsncode = $item->getHsnCode();
                    echo $name;
                    echo $hsncode;                
                }
            }
```

**Product name is displayed but hsn_code was not displayed.**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Object method

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($item->getProductId());
echo $product->getHsnCode();
```

Factory Method

```
<?php
namespace Test\Module\Block;

class Product extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

  protected $_productloader;  


  public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $_productloader
        
    ) {

       
        $this->_productloader = $_productloader;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
    public function getLoadProduct($id)
    {
        return $this->_productloader->create()->load($id);
    }
    public function execute($id)
    {
        $product=$this->getLoadProduct($item->getProductId());
        $hsnCode = $product->getHsnCode(); 
    }


}
```

In Magento 2.1

```
<?php
    namespace Test\Module\Block;
    use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
    class Product extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
     {
          protected $productRepository; 
          protected $_storeManager; 

          public function __construct(
            \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
            ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
          ) {
              parent::__construct($context);

              $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
          }
          public function getProduct()
          {

              $productId=1;
              return $product = $this->productRepository->getById($productId);
          }
      }
```

[Reference](https://blog.qaisarsatti.com/magento_2/magento-2-load-product-by-id/)

Comment: when i fetch  this value 
$GstHsnCode          = $this->helperData->execute();
            echo $GstHsnCode;

Comment: ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function Ncode\GSTtax\Helper\Data::execute(), 0 passed in /var/www/html/m243new/app/code/Ncode/GSTtax/Model/Quote/Total/Fee.php on line 74 and exactly 1 expected in /var/www/html/m243new/app/code/Ncode/GSTtax/Helper/Data.php:153

Comment: please dont add code in execute function of your helper. remove it

Comment: now add ``$product=$this->helperData->getLoadProduct($item->getProductId());
      echo  $hsnCode = $product->getHsnCode(); ``